# pthread in C, incompatible type

Tags: c, pthreads

while compiling, i got this error

```
expected 'union pthread_mutex_t *' but argument is type of 'pthread_mutex_t'
```

1) what is the difference between 'union pthread_mutex_t *' and 'pthread_mutex_t'?
2) How do i make 'pthread_mutex_t' into the correct argument?

```
void buffer_insert(int number)
{
  pthread_mutex_t padlock;
  pthread_cond_t non_full;
  pthread_mutex_init(&padlock, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&non_full, NULL);
  if(available_buffer()){
    put_in_buffer(number);
  } else {
    pthread_mutex_lock(padlock);
    pthread_cond_wait(non_full, padlock);
    put_in_buffer(number);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(padlock);
    pthread_cond_signal(non_empty);
  }
}
```

Comment: Care to show some code ?

Comment: `pthread_mutex_lock(&padlock);` and `pthread_cond_wait(&non_full, &padlock);` and `pthread_mutex_unlock(&padlock);` etc... Most pthread functions take their parameters by address; only a few do not.

Comment: NPE has already explained the pointer part, for the 'union' keyword you can assume that variables of different datatypes and probably different sizes may be expected to share the same memory location(this is normally used for int, unsigned, float, long etc sharing a memory location). This is a handy technique one doesn't want to constrain a piece of data to be of a particular type.

Comment: That code doesn't "lock" anything - because `padlock` is a _local variable_, every invocation of `buffer_insert()` will use a _different_ lock. Please don't code it this way.

Comment: @FrankH. yeah I have fixed that long time ago. everything works now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The asterisk in

```
int pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex);
```

means that the function takes a [*pointer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#C_pointers) to `pthread_mutex_t`.

You need to take the address of your mutex variable, i.e. replace `padlock` with `&padlock` when calling the function.

For example,

```
pthread_mutex_lock(padlock);
```

should read

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&padlock);
```

and so on (for both the mutex and the condition variable).

It is also worth noting that in the code you show, `padlock` and `non_full` are local to the function, and are created and destroyed every time the function is called. Therefore no synchronization is taking place. You need to rethink how you declare and initialize the two variables.

There are further problems with the code. For example, the way you're using the condition variable is flawed in several respects.

With this in mind, I'd recommend following a pthreads tutorial.

Comment: -1 for "should read". Too short-sighted. The code is broken, and just by making it compile one doesn't yet make it work.